# get publisher class field from sender

Tags: c#, events, sender

I want to get my field >>> **NumberOfElementsInMyList** from sender, How Can I do it?  I couldn't find this kind of question here (what I have seen, was about windows forms), so ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher PublisherObject = new Publisher();
        PublisherObject.NumberAdded += PublisherObject_NumberAdded;

        PublisherObject.AddNumber(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static void PublisherObject_NumberAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I want to write on the console  "NumberOfElementsInMylist"

        //I tried: 

        //sender.NumberOfElementsInMylist -- not works
        //Publisher obj=(publisher)sender   and then sender.NumberOfElementsInMylist
        //not works
        Console.WriteLine("number of elements in list is ---> "+ ???? );
    }
}

class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler NumberAdded;

    public int NumberOfElementsInMyList;

    List<int> MyList=new List<int>();

    public void AddNumber(int NumberToAdd)
    {
        MyList.Add(NumberToAdd);

        NumberOfElementsInMyList = MyList.Count;

        NumberAdded(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what is the current output ? Is there error thrown ?

Comment: there is no error, I can't access publisher class field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To literally answer your question, the reason why you can't access the `NumberOfElementsInMyList` field is because when you create the `EventArgs`, your instance of `Publisher` is being cast as an `object` (which you can do since all classes inherit from object.) So to see the properties (or field) of `Publisher`, you have to cast the `sender` as `Publisher`.

```
var numberOfElements = ((Publisher)sender).NumberOfElementsInMyList;
```

A downside to this is that hypothetically, `sender` might not be a `Publisher`. Because `sender` is an `object`, it could technically be anything.

You can also create your own event handler delegate and event args instead of using the boilerplate `EventHandler` delegate.

```
public delegate void NumberAdded(Publisher source, NumberAddedEventArgs eventArgs);

public class NumberAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public NumberAddedEventArgs(int numberAdded, numberOfItemsInList)
    {
        NumberAdded = numberAdded;
        NumberOfItemsInList = numberOfItemsInList;
    }

    public int NumberAdded { get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfItemsInList { get; private set; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler NumberAddedEvent;

    public int NumberOfElementsInMyList;

    List<int> MyList = new List<int>();

    public void AddNumber(int NumberToAdd)
    {
        MyList.Add(NumberToAdd);

        NumberOfElementsInMyList = MyList.Count;

        NumberAddedEvent?.Invoke(this, new NumberAddedEventArgs(NumberToAdd, 
            NumberOfElementsInMyList));
    }
}

var numberOfElementsInList = args.NumberOfItemsInList; // much better!
```

The `(object sender, EventArgs args)` is a strange convention. In any other scenario we would create strongly-typed methods and delegates. But in this case there's a tendency to use something that's not strongly-typed because it's a convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the `sender`, can't you?

```
var publisher = (Publisher)sender;
Console.WriteLine(publisher.NumberOfElementsInMyList);
```

Or more safely:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    (sender as Publisher)?.NumberOfElementsInMyList?.ToString() ?? "sender is not a publisher!");
```

Comment: @Beginner if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!